# Custom link on home page

Tags: home-page-component

in home page i have a custom link which redirects to outlook mail and for that I have used a javascript like this

```
window.location.href = "mailto:xyz.abc.com".
```

It works properly in chrome and firefox and other IE versions. But when it comes to Internet explorer 9, it is seen that upon clicking the link, a blank tab is always open with passing the mail address in URL even though it is redirected to outlook mail and always the user has to click on backspace to return to main page.

Could you please let me know if it is a problem with IE9?

Comment: Is this the same behavoir as on plain HTML pages in those browsers ? This doesn't really look salesforce related, but HTML/browser specific. In that regard it'd may make more sense to inquire about this in a microsoft or html community.

Comment: please consider to use email addresses.. and in addition: why are you using javascript? is there any reason?